# Unable to transfer funds to contract address using Brownie

Tags: evm, error, bsc, brownie

I have deployed a contract, *testContract*, onto bsc testnet

I have a test wallet with sufficient funds and can seemingly make transfers to other wallet addresses without any issues.

I am just trying to load the *testContract* address with wBNB.

```
me = accounts.load(abc)
me2 = accounts.load(xyz)
me.transfer(me2.address, 100)
```

This all works fine with no issues. But if I try:

```
me.transfer(*contract_address*, 100)
```

I get:

> Gas estimation failed: 'execution reverted'. This transaction will likely revert. If you wish to broadcast, you must set the gas limit manually.

If I manually enter gas parameters I am met with 'execution reverted'. I have no idea what is going on :(

Answer (score 1):

Per the [solidity docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.10/contracts.html?highlight=receive#receive-ether-function)

> Contracts that receive Ether directly (without a function call, i.e. using send or transfer) but do not define a receive Ether function or a payable fallback function throw an exception,sending back the Ether (this was different before Solidity v0.4.0).

This means, you need to define a `receive` function in the contract in order for it to be able to accept ETH (or, BNB, in the case of binance smart chain)